Android inapp billing bug?
ok i don't know what's happening.
I'm testing in app billing for a single non-consumable product in my android app. I'm using billing v6.2.1 (the latest version). I can fetch the products then open/show the purchase sheet correctly. Then, I can buy my product, and that's successful (I have the order in the Order Management of my Play Console). Furthermore, the billing api returns a purchased product in the app:
Purchase. Json: {"orderId":"GPA.3325-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx","packageName":"com.example","productId":"com.example.premium","purchaseTime":1714235557168,"purchaseState":0,"purchaseToken":"blablablabla.somethingsomethingblablabla","quantity":1,"acknowledged":false}

But when i restart my app the product is gone! When I fetch the purchases, its not there. And i can buy the product again an pay it multiple times!? I've bought the product 10 times now, and it appears 10 times in my Order Management, with 10 purchased emails from Google.

        purchasesUpdatedListener =
            PurchasesUpdatedListener { billingResult, purchases ->
                Log.d(TAG, "PurchasesUpdatedListener ${billingResult.responseCode}")
                if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases != null) {
                    for (purchase in purchases) {
                        coroutineScope?.launch {
                            handlePurchase(purchase)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // Handle any other error codes.
                    // TODO
                }
            }

        billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(context)
                .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
                .enablePendingPurchases()
                .build()

        Log.d(TAG, "Starting connection...")
        billingClient.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
            override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onBillingSetupFinished ${billingResult.responseCode} ${billingResult.debugMessage}")
                if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onBillingSetupFinished OK")

                    val queryProductDetailsParams = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                            .setProductList(
                                ImmutableList.of(
                                    QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                                            .setProductId(Constants.PREMIUM_ID)
                                            .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP)
                                            .build()
                                )
                            )
                            .build()

                    billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(queryProductDetailsParams) { billingResult2, productDetailsList ->
                        productDetailsList.forEach { productDetails ->
                            if (productDetails.productId == Constants.PREMIUM_ID) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Product fetched, adding to list: ${productDetails.productId}")
                                fetchedProductsGoogleList.add(productDetails)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
                // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
                // TODO
                Log.d(TAG, "onBillingServiceDisconnected")
            }
        })


"When I fetch the purchases, its not there." - Explain what "fetch the purchases" and "it's not there" mean.
